# What is not defined method type in $.ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

What if we don't explicitly define the type: in Ajax setup or ajax call will it take any default?

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
  url: "/xmlhttp/",
  global: false,
  type: "POST"
});
$.ajax({ data: myData });
```

Comment: Yes, Default `type:` is `GET`!

Comment: Check it in official docs of [jQuery Ajax settings](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

Comment: [RTFM](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/)

Comment: @OP: Did you know that calling `$.ajax()` without any parameter is also valid and will send a XmlHttpRequest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Default Type in $.ajax is GET , you can test it in your firebug or web inspector tool also !***

[Check out here !](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)